# How do I install a patch if folder set for msiexec TARGETDIR property is permanently deleted

Tags: windows-installer

I have created a silent installation batch script to install msi and msp in a single step as below

```
for /r %%i in (*.msi) do set msifile=%%i
for /r %%i in (*.msp) do set mspfile=%%i

msiexec /a "%msifile%" TARGETDIR="%programdata%\FOLDER" /qn

cd %programdata%\AC72AIP

for /r %%i in (*.msi) do set msifile=%%i  
msiexec /a "%msifile%" /p "%mspfile%" /qn  :: This creates AIP in the C:\ProgramData\FOLDER
msiexec /i "%msifile%" /qn                 :: This command installs the AIP from C:\ProgramData\FOLDER

cd C:\
rmdir /Q /S %programdata%\FOLDER
```

msifile is installer.msi and mspfile is patch1.msp.

Now when I try to do manual Apply of patch2.msp, i get a window asking for source msi with below message

"The installed product does not match the installation source.Until a matching source is provided or the installed product and source are synchronized, this action cannot be performed."

Since the `%programdata%\FOLDER` is deleted I cannot go to the actual source. I have tried all option of msiexec command but could not find a solution for this error. Can someone suggest what can be done to install second patch(patch2.msp) without reinstalling the product.

Comment: Will look later, but maybe you can patch the administration image for your original installer? That is essentially patching the installation files instead of the installed product: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/applying-a-patch-package-to-an-administrative-installation - often fails, but give it a try.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul As mentioned in the question the AIP is created on user machines in ProgramData and then the AIP is being deleted. I re-created the AIP with the same patch and the software gets reinstalled, but when I try to apply new patch after this, the msi installer  looks for files in C:\Config.Msi throwing error `Error 1328:Error applying patch to file C:\Config.Msi\XXXXX.tmp. It has probably been updated by other means, and can no longer be modified by this patch.` I am unsure how to resolve this error.